# Server.MapPath not working into Web forms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to use Server.MapPath in my Web Form (Windows Form App) But it is not taking 
error :

```
LinkedResource resource = new LinkedResource((Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.MapPath("Images\007jvr.gif")));
```

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'MapPath' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

What I need to do?

Comment: are you getting file from SQL?  you can use  HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Images\007jvr.gif");

Comment: I assume you do mean Web Form - cos thats not the same as a Windows Form. Are you using it in a aspx page or a code file or ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this syntax to get file from Folder.

```
    LinkedResource resource = new 
LinkedResource(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Images\007jvr.gif"));
```